# JUnit Parameterized @BeforeAll

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I'm a beginner at JUnit, I got a problem when I am learning it. I did a lot of searches, but still can't find the answer.

The version of JUnit Jupiter I'm using is 5.3.0-M1.

---

I'm doing tests on some sorting algorithms. I'd like to test if they are correct, and the performance on different arrays with different length. Here is my solution.

@BeforeAll
Generated a random unsorted array as `source`, and a `target` array which is a sorted.

@BeforeEach
Copy the unsorted `source` to a new array as `inputs` ready for the test.

Each @Test method sorts the `inputs` array and compares it with `target`, so I know if it is correct, and the IDE will tell me how much time it cost.

---

The **problem** is: I have to manually change the `length` every time, and test it again.

I wonder if there is a way to setup up the test, so it will run for each different length I set.
For example, pass an array like [16, 32, 64, ...] as different length I want to test with.

I know I can pass parameters to @Test method, but then I have to generate `source` and `target` multiple times in each @Test.

(Sorry for my bad English, I hope I have explained the problem clearly enough.)

Here is my test class looks like:

```
class SortingTest {

    static int length = 512;    // manually change every time.
//  static int length = 1024;
//  static int length = 2048;
//  static int length = 4096;

    static int[] source;
    static int[] target;
    static int[] inputs;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAllSort() {
        source = MintArray.generateIntArray(length);
        target = new int[length];
        inputs = new int[length];
        System.arraycopy(source, 0, target, 0, source.length);
        Arrays.sort(target);
        System.out.println("[SORT] Array Length : [" + length + "]");
        System.out.println("[SORT] Source Array : " + Arrays.toString(source));
        System.out.println("[SORT] Target Array : " + Arrays.toString(target));
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEachSort() {
        System.arraycopy(source, 0, inputs, 0, source.length);
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Bubble Sort")
    void bubbleSort() {
        System.out.println("[SORT] Bubble Sort");
        inputs = new BubbleSort().bubbleSort(inputs);
        assertArrayEquals(inputs, target);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Insertion Sort")
    void insertionSort() {
        System.out.println("[SORT] Insertion Sort");
        inputs = new InsertionSort().insertionSort(inputs);
        assertArrayEquals(inputs, target);
    }

    @Test
    .......more sort
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `@ParameterizedTest` with `@MethodSource` instead of manually doing all this with `@Test` methods?

Comment: Sam Brannen, thank you so much, @MethodSource works!  ^_^